# Изменить столбец с датами в датафрейме по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Исходный датафрейм:

```
 ID    date             amount
  1    2018-09-03 17:00:00  7282.5
  2    2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0   
  3    2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0    
  4    2018-09-10 18:00:00  6377.0 
  5    2018-09-15 14:00:00  6376.5
```

На вход получаю список праздничных дней
`holydays = [3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

Нужно получить:

```
 ID    date                 amount
  1    2018-09-05 17:00:00  7282.5
  2    2018-09-05 11:00:00  7111.0   
  3    2018-09-08 10:00:00  6448.0    
  4    2018-09-14 18:00:00  6377.0 
  5    2018-09-15 14:00:00  6376.5
```

То есть если дата попадает на праздник, ее нужно изменить на следующую после праздников.

Пытался так:

```
df.loc[df['date'].dt.day.isin(holydays), 
           'date'] = df['date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

И так:

```
for x in df['date']:
    while x.day in holydays:
        x = x + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Во втором варианте похоже чего-то не хватает...

Comment: 10-е выходной, 11-е, 12-е и 13-е тоже. То есть следующий рабочий день 14-е

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку воспроизводимые данные не представлены, пишу код без проверки. Код не оптимальный, но должен работать по идее:

```
while True:
    df_holydays_mask = df['date'].dt.day.isin(holydays)
    if not holidays_mask.any():
        break
    df.loc[df_holydays_mask, 'date'] = \
        df.loc[df_holydays_mask, 'date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Суть - пока в `df` есть праздничные дни, берём эти дни и увеличиваем все скопом на 1.

Но вообще по-хорошему праздники должны быть привязаны к полной дате, а не только к дню месяца, несколько странно у вас, что просто день берётся.

Comment: Отлично, работает. Спасибо! Исходные данные, период - ровно за месяц поступают, поэтому смысла в полной дате нет.

Comment: @FedorMelnikov Тогда отметьте мой ответ как полезный/правильный, там есть специальная галочка или что-то вроде того )

Comment: Поставил сразу, выскакивает оповещение: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: А если мне нужна маска по условию, например только там где время >12:00:00. Пишу df_holydays_mask = df.loc[(df['time'] > 12:00:00), df['date']].dt.day.isin(holydays), далее так же. Ошибка выскакивает IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).